# 3 snooker balls in a box

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A regulation snooker ball is 52.5 mm in diameter.  What are the **minimum** internal dimensions of a cube that can exactly contain 3 of them?  I'm sure there must be an easy answer, but I'm not a mathematician and I don't know how to calculate that answer.  And it's keeping me awake at night.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as for 4 snooker balls, see

http://www.randomwalk.de/sphere/incube/pages/n03d585786.htm

and

http://www.randomwalk.de/sphere/incube/pages/n04d585786.htm

Give me a minute, I will tell you the side of the cube in terms of the radius of the spheres

Alrighty, the edge of the cube is $(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$ times the diameter of the balls. 
$$ 1.707106781 \cdot 55.5 = 94.74442635 \; \mbox{mm}   $$

There is a good way to place four spheres of equal radius in a cube, using coordinates. The four centers are at
$$ (1,1,1), (1,-1,-1), (-1,1,-1), (-1,-1,1).   $$
Any two of these centers are exactly $2 \sqrt 2$ apart, so the radius of the spheres is $\sqrt 2.$ The largest $x$ value of any point on any sphere is $1 + \sqrt 2$ at
$$ (1 + \sqrt 2,1,1) \; \;   \mbox{OR} \; \;  (1 + \sqrt 2,-1,-1) $$
The smallest $x$ value of any point on any sphere is $-1 - \sqrt 2.$ The difference is the edge length of the cube,
$$ 1 + \sqrt 2 - (-1 - \sqrt 2) = 2 + 2 \sqrt 2.  $$ As a multiple of the radius, 
$$  \frac{2 + 2 \sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 + 2. $$ However, as a multiple of the diameter, we get instead
$$  \frac{2 + 2 \sqrt 2}{2 \sqrt 2} = 1 + \frac{1}{ \sqrt 2} . $$

I had it wrong initially; note that our smallest cube should have edge less than two diameters, because with two diameters we can fit 8 snooker balls.

From the same website, they say proofs are available up to 10 balls. In this table, they give the reciprocal, in that they say the cube is side $1$ and they are giving the diameter of the largest spheres.

```
# Densest Packings of n Equal Spheres in a Cube of Edge Length 1
# Largest Possible Diameters
# Author: Hugo Pfoertner http://www.pfoertner.org/
# URL of this file: http://www.randomwalk.de/sphere/incube/spicbest.txt
# Date of last update: YYYY MM DD
2005 06 03
#n  Diameter  Originator
 1  1.0 'common sense'
 2  0.6339746 'common sense'
 3  0.5857864 'J. Schaer'
 4  0.5857864 'J. Schaer'
 5  0.527864 'J. Schaer'
 6  0.5147186 'J. Schaer'
 7  0.5002723 'J. Schaer'
 8  0.5 'J. Schaer'
 9  0.4641016 'J. Schaer'
10  0.4285714 'J. Schaer'
```

Comment: Forgive me, but why 1 + sq root of 2?  BTW that's what I came up with (approx), using pen, paper, compass and ruler.  But it took an hour.....

Comment: Hugo Pfoertner seems to have found the answers for umpteen different $n$ by computer search. Without spending a lot of time looking at his software there is no way of knowing whether he is right. Or, to be more accurate, it is probably quicker to try to prove it directly. :)

Comment: @ChrisHaws, corrected and explained.